# JMeter v.5+ - how to change retrieved embedded resources format in JMeter v5.2.1 to get full urls?

Tags: url, jmeter, embedded-resource

In JMeter 5.2.1, by default I have response with embedded resources in abstract format like that:

domain/path

- domain/path-0
- domain/path-1
- domain/path-2
- domain/path-3
  ... 
  (etc.)

I need to see normal URLs to each embedded resource instead of these abstract suffixes with -0,-1,-2,-3 etc. (like it worked in JMeter v.3).

How is it possible to set up, to have embedded resources in format of full URLs for each embedded resource?
Could you please give me a tip or lifehack for that for JMeter v.5+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something you **really** need, you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (it lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

```
subresults.disable_renaming=true
```

For one-time usage the property can be overridden via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jsubresults.disable_renaming=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them. You might also be interested in [Settings that affect SampleResults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#sample_results) chapter of JMeter Properties Reference

However you should be doing this only if you plan to use JMeter for some form of functional testing because it will break the logic of HTTP Request sampler elapsed time calculation in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for high qualified answer with additional info. It definitely works with URLs as I need.